# inotifywait get only on event when create directory

Tags: bash

I want to run service to listen on directory modifying and for every add or file modify run a function but I get more one event from adding directory

```
inotifywait -rm -e create,modify "$dir" |
while read folder eventlist eventfile
do
   echo $folder $eventlist  $eventfile
done
```

when I add one directory 'ssss' output:

```
/root/business_layer/ CREATE,ISDIR ssss
/root/business_layer/ssss/ CREATE 1
/root/business_layer/ssss/ MODIFY 1
/root/business_layer/ssss/ CREATE www
/root/business_layer/ssss/ MODIFY www
/root/business_layer/ssss/ CREATE 112
/root/business_layer/ssss/ MODIFY 112
/root/business_layer/ssss/ CREATE asd
```

is there any way to get only /root/business_layer/ CREATE,ISDIR ssss

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean.

The events you want to discard concern the contents of the newly-created directory *ssss*. They appear in your log only because you have specified the recursive option, *-r*, so that they can be dropped just by issuing the same command without that option. This way, you will be watching only the top directory, */root/business_layer*, not its subdirectories.

Is this what you want?

Comment: I have subdirectories `dir="/root"`

Comment: I want to listen and for every event upload it to Team Foundation Server